# How can I record video with single camera module of smartphones?

Tags: camera

I want to record video apart from my smartphone(Let's say Samsung Galaxy S3) taking out it's camera module.I think it is possible because camera's microchip comes with itself.I mean I will connect camera to micro SD and I will give wanted DC current from battery and camera records and sends video to my micro SD card.If it is possible how can I do it?And how much voltage will be needed to record video continously?

Comment: No. Is doesn't work that way. The camera module has no way of writing directly to an SD card.

Comment: There is quite a bit of logic that goes between a camera and an SD card, for example, the file system code.

Comment: There are of course camera modules sold (keychain cameras, micro drone cameras, etc) which record directly to SD card.  But the camera sensors used in phones do not work that way - instead the provide data which must be processed by the computer that comprises the core of the phone.  Given that you're trying to treat the camera module like a black box function, this is an off topic consumer electronics usage question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question shows no understanding of how the camera works, how SD works, the amount of processing that is required between the two or how electricity is used to do what you want. You need much study.

> ... and camera records and sends video to my micro SD card. If it is possible how can I do it?

To solve your problem you could connect the camera to the SD card using the circuits of a smartphone. i.e. Just use your phone.